# Feature test for command line program Ruby / RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a script that I want to run within some tests using RSpec that I want to test the input / output on.

For example,

I have a script 'script.rb' that I run using 'ruby script.rb'

The script then outputs to STDOUT and takes an input using STDIN. I want to test this using RSPec and check that everything works appropriately (a feature test). How would I go about doing this? Just do an execute 'ruby script.rb' within RSPec and then test that the output is what I expect and that it takes input from STDIN?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to test your script as a black box (only STDIN/STDOUT), you may perfectly do it via `system()` call: just make sure to clean up all side effects your script is leaving (for example, temporary files).

**EDIT**: Just create some file with needed content, say `stdin.txt`.

After that you may run your command this way:

```
system('cat stdin.txt | ruby myscript.rb')
```

Comment: ok, is there a way to fake stdin for gets calls to the script so I dont have to manually have the tester input something? similar to the fill_in method in capybara for web requests

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line `system("printf 'y\ny\ny\n' | ./script")`